# Access ServiceBean from EJB3

Tags: ejb-3.0, jboss6.x

i implements this [tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/service/src/org/jboss/tutorial/service/bean/ServiceTwo.java), but i cant access the service from EJB3.

My ejb looks like this:

```
@Stateless
public class Authentication implements AuthenticationRemote {

  private ServiceTwoManagement man;

  ...    

}
```

@EJB will throw: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve @EJB reference:`

Any Suggestions

Comment: Give us the complete stack trace and your Interface 'AuthenticationRemote' as well showing all the annotations and imports . Also show where are you calling it from and how.Also show the class deceleration and interface(if applicable) along with all annotations of the class which is calling this.The link you have is a small class.

Comment: Sorry @JavaKaBaby, meanwhile i found an solution and dont like to reproduce the old state. So ill answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guys had no chance to post an concrete answer (many informations hidden), i currently found either an clean solution or an buggy workaround. In second case: i would be glad to see any better solution like i found.

**My solution was to create an service-bean (3rd bean) hold's all the TransportObjects.**

*@Service* defines an Singleton, so i get close to the GoF-Pattern using the Singleton-Pattern.

Finally my solution looks like this:

```
package org.gegenakw.ejb.user;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javassist.NotFoundException;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.antiakw.exceptions.authentication.AccountAlreadyExistsException;
import org.antiakw.exceptions.authentication.IllegalLoginException;
import org.antiakw.exceptions.authentication.NotYetActivatedException;
import org.gegenakw.Utils;
import org.gegenakw.ejb.extern.RegistrationEmailsTransportObjectHolder;
import org.gegenakw.ejb.interfaces.RegistrationTransferObject;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.hibernate.validator.InvalidStateException;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Depends;

import de.antiakw.jpa.beans.Benutzer;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class Authentication
 */
@Stateless
public class Authentication implements AuthenticationRemote {

  public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Authentication");

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "gegenakwjpa")
  Session hibernateSession;

  // @EJB
  private List<RegistrationTransferObject> registration = RegistrationEmailsTransportObjectHolder.getInstance();

  @Override
  public void createAccountCheckDuplicates(String email, String pass)
      throws InvalidStateException, AccountAlreadyExistsException {
    ...
  } 

  ...
}
```

My RETOH looks like this:

```
package org.gegenakw.ejb.extern;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.gegenakw.ejb.interfaces.RegistrationTransferObject;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Management;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Service;

@Service(objectName = "gegen-akw:service=RETOH")
@Management(List.class)
public class RegistrationEmailsTransportObjectHolder extends ArrayList<RegistrationTransferObject> {

  private static RegistrationEmailsTransportObjectHolder me;

  public static RegistrationEmailsTransportObjectHolder getInstance() {
    return me;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void create() throws Exception {
    me = this;

  }

}
```

And my Job looks like this:

```
package de.antiakw.service.email;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.SMIMEException;
import org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.SMIMESignedGenerator;
import org.gegenakw.ejb.interfaces.RegistrationTransferObject;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Depends;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.ResourceAdapter;
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

@ResourceAdapter("quartz-ra.rar")
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "cronTrigger", propertyValue = "0 * * * * ?") }

)
public class RegistrationEmails implements Job {

  public static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("RegistrationEmails");

  private static java.security.cert.Certificate certificate;

  @Depends("gegen-akw:service=RETOH")
  private List<RegistrationTransferObject> registrationMailHolder;

  @Resource(mappedName = "java:Gegen-AKW-Mailsystem")
  javax.mail.Session mailSession;

  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    synchronized (registrationMailHolder) {
```

@JavaKaBaby: to folow your needs, i post my stactrace using @EJB instad of singleton-pattern (i hope the problem is comprehesible withal my workaround):

```
09:51:21,577 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfs:///C:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/gegen-akw.ear state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real: org.jboss.dep
loyers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: org.jboss.metadata.ejb.jboss.JBossEnterpriseBeanMetaData.Authentication
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:185) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1603) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve @EJB reference: [EJB Reference: beanInterface 'java.util.List', beanName 'null', mappedName 'null', lookupName 'null', owning unit 'ComponentDe
ploymentContext@848640405{org.jboss.metadata.ejb.jboss.JBossEnterpriseBeanMetaData.Authentication}'] for environment entry: env/org.gegenakw.ejb.user.Authentication/registration in unit ComponentDeplo
ymentContext@848640405{org.jboss.metadata.ejb.jboss.JBossEnterpriseBeanMetaData.Authentication}
        at org.jboss.ejb3.jndi.deployers.resource.provider.AnnotatedEJBRefResourceProvider.provide(AnnotatedEJBRefResourceProvider.java:99) [:0.1.7]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.jndi.deployers.resource.provider.AnnotatedEJBRefResourceProvider.provide(AnnotatedEJBRefResourceProvider.java:50) [:0.1.7]
        at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.JndiEnvironmentProcessor.process(JndiEnvironmentProcessor.java:68) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
        at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.deployer.AbstractSwitchBoardDeployer.process(AbstractSwitchBoardDeployer.java:119) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
        at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.deployer.EJBEnvironmentSwitchBoardDeployer.internalDeploy(EJBEnvironmentSwitchBoardDeployer.java:87) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
        ... 45 more
```